# PHP complex multi arrays sorting and filtering results

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, directory

I am trying to learn PHP arrays and build a page for showcasing my 3D materials made with substance designer.

I have searched the internet but lost on how best to complete what I require.

The feature I am trying to achieve is to display a directory on the server with all the items in folders in a grid system. I have made all the ways to upload my 3D materials via a form and unzip to the categories but can't find out how to display the array into a grid.

My files on the server look like this but the categories could grow.

[Folders on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD3cQ.png)

I am using the below code to make a multiple array of the folder directory.

```
    function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $fileInfo     = scandir($dir);
    $allFileLists = [];

    foreach ($fileInfo as $folder)
    {

        if ($folder !== '.' && $folder !== '..')
        {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder) === true)
            {
                // This is the asset cat folder - ceramic - fabric so on
                $allFileLists[$folder] = listFolderFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is sub folder file like image and asset
                $allFileLists[$folder] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }



    return $allFileLists;
}//end listFolderFiles()


$dir = listFolderFiles('my_directory');
```

The above output the following array's via "var_dump($dir);"

```
  array(17) {
  ["Ceramic"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Concrete - Asphalt"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Fabric"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Terrazzo Generator"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Preview.jpg"]=>
      string(11) "Preview.jpg"
      ["concrete_terrazzo_generator.sbsar"]=>
      string(33) "concrete_terrazzo_generator.sbsar"
    }
    ["White Test"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["image.jpg"]=>
      string(9) "image.jpg"
      ["leather_diamond_quilt_double_stitch.sbsar"]=>
      string(41) "leather_diamond_quilt_double_stitch.sbsar"
    }
    ["White Test2"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["image.jpg"]=>
      string(9) "image.jpg"
      ["leather_diamond_quilt_double_stitch.sbsar"]=>
      string(41) "leather_diamond_quilt_double_stitch.sbsar"
    }
  }
  ["Ground"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Leather"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Marble - Granite"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Metal"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Organic"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Paint"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Paper"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Plaster"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Plastic - Rubber"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Signature"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Stone"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Terracotta"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Translucent"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Wood"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["European Ash"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["wood_european_ash.sbsar"]=>
      string(23) "wood_european_ash.sbsar"
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I wish to do is display the results in a grid system to show the image in the folder and category. I'm confident in creating the grid system to display the content but I am unable to loop over the multi array to create the grid system. I need to make sure that any empty folders in the categories do not show in the grid and only the sub folders inside show up.

As the above array out put [wood] & [fabric] contain sub folders. Ordering does not matter as I will use jQuery to search or filter on the page.

Grid system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxZLe.jpg)

I am probably doing this all wrong but it is the only way I can come up with at present.

Any help you can give me to be able to filter the array system would be grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Give sample of your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Playing with directories and files as you are is often fiddly. Ideally you'd have the data mapped in a DB, so you'd have references to each directory and data in it. When you upload an image, a table field will have a true value, etc.

However, working with traversing directory structures as this is what you have, you could change how your array is structured so you have access to more convenient identifiers (keys) and have non-empty dirs in the array. Such as:

```
[0]
    [
        'category' => 'Ceramic',
        'name' => 'white test',
        'imageName' => 'Preview.jpg',
    ],
[1]
    [
        'category' => 'whatever',
        'name' => 'something',
        'imageName' => 'image.jpg',
    ],
```

Notice how there's no "Concrete - Asphalt" because if no files then don't have it in the array, then you can just loop the array knowing it should have data.

If you need the dir name for some reason, have an identifier that the dir was empty, eg:

```
[0]
    [
        'category' => 'Ceramic',
        'name' => 'white test',
        'imageName' => 'Preview.jpg',
        'hasValues' = true,
    ],
[1]
    [
        'category' => 'Concrete - Asphalt',
        'hasValues' = false,
    ],
```

Then you can check if `hasValues` is true etc.

Here's a quick script that might help, will get that array setup. There's possibly a cleaner way, but given no DB this is pretty decent imo

```
function getAllFromDir($dirToSearch)
{
    return new FilesystemIterator($dirToSearch, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
}

function listFolderFiles($dirToSearch)
{
    $allFileLists = [];
    $allDirs = getAllFromDir($dirToSearch);
    $newKey = 0;
    $imageTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];

    foreach ($allDirs as $dir) {

        $allFileLists[$newKey]['category'] = (string) $dir->getFilename();
        $parentSubDir = getAllFromDir($dir);

        if (iterator_count($parentSubDir) < 1) {
            $allFileLists[$newKey]['hasFiles'] = false;
            $newKey++;
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($parentSubDir as $subDir) {

            $allFileLists[$newKey]['name'] = (string) $subDir->getFilename();
            $files = getAllFromDir($subDir);

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $ext = (string) $file->getExtension();
                $keyName = in_array($ext, $imageTypes) ? 'image' : $ext;
                $allFileLists[$newKey][$keyName] = (string) $file->getFilename();
            }

            $allFileLists[$newKey]['hasFiles'] = true;
            $newKey++;
        }
    }

    return $allFileLists;
}
```

For a DIR structure:

```
[dir] concrete
[dir] fabric
    [dir] white test2
        [file] image.jpg
        [file] testfile.sbsar
```

Then the above script will output the following:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => fabric
            [name] => white test2
            [image] => image.jpg
            [sbsar] => testfile.sbsar
            [hasFiles] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => concrete
            [hasFiles] => false
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks @james it kind of works, The output is as you have stated above but it does not output all the items or categories.

Comment: I have found out why the items are not showing all. $newKey++; should be under $allFileLists[$newKey]['hasFiles'] = true; and not outside the foreach. And under $allFileLists[$newKey]['hasFiles'] = false; also to show all folders that don't have items not just one. Thank you for your help! If you can edit the code above I will vote it up :-).. Thanks again

Comment: I'll change it, but that is the outer key that contains each parent dir. But if it works no probs :)

Comment: It works the way I edited the code. Thank you so much made my life easier and as after I posted I tried to do some of adding key names but my code is not as advanced as the one you did. I now have a working page and was able to unset directories that had no items making it smoother! Cheers James your a star!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)